# Querying DBpedia with SPARQL and Jena

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, jena, dbpedia

I cannot understand how can I query DBpedia using Jena. In the tutorials like [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/j-sparql/#side2)(Listing 4) model is initialized as follows:

```java
// Open the bloggers RDF graph from the filesystem
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("bloggers.rdf"));

// Create an empty in-memory model and populate it from the graph
Model model = ModelFactory.createMemModelMaker().createModel();
model.read(in,null); // null base URI, since model URIs are absolute
in.close();
```

Let's say I want to write a query that will list churches in Paris. In SPARQL it will look like (taken from [this mailing list message](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-lod/2009Oct/0040.html)):

```
PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?m ?n ?p ?d
WHERE {
 ?m rdfs:label ?n.
 ?m skos:subject ?c.
 ?c skos:broader category:Churches_in_Paris.
 ?m p:abstract ?d.
 ?m geo:point ?p
 FILTER ( lang(?n) = "fr" )
 FILTER ( lang(?d) = "fr" )
 }
```

How will this query look in Java?  Particularly, I'm interested in how the model object is initialized.

Comment: Do  you want to know how to run SPARQL queries in Jena, or a procedure that performs an equivalent query to that one?

Comment: Yes. Actually I found an answer which I was looking for but I would look with pleasure to your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After browsing tons and tons of pages I found the answer. Perhaps I didn't ask the question clearly enough, but anyway below is the code that worked for me.

```java
String queryString=
"PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>"+
"PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>"+
"PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>"+
"PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+
"PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>"+
"PREFIX geo: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>"+

"SELECT DISTINCT ?m ?n ?p ?d"+
"WHERE {"+
" ?m rdfs:label ?n."+
" ?m skos:subject ?c."+
" ?c skos:broader category:Churches_in_Paris."+
" ?m p:abstract ?d."+
" ?m geo:point ?p"+
" FILTER ( lang(?n) = "fr" )"+
" FILTER ( lang(?d) = "fr" )"+
" }"

// now creating query object
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
// initializing queryExecution factory with remote service.
// **this actually was the main problem I couldn't figure out.**
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);

//after it goes standard query execution and result processing which can
// be found in almost any Jena/SPARQL tutorial.
try {
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
    for (; results.hasNext();) {

    // Result processing is done here.
    }
}
finally {
   qexec.close();
}
```

This answer I found on [dbpedia-discussion of www.mail-archive.com page](http://www.mail-archive.com/dbpedia-discussion@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01086.html).

Comment: The code in this answer isn't quite right, and contains some subtle bugs.  String concatenation like `"SELECT DISTINCT ?m ?n ?p ?d"+
"WHERE {"` leads to "SELECT DISTINCT ... ?dWHERE {` with a variable named `dWHERE` (and this is still legal, since the `WHERE` in a SPARQL where is optional;  i.e.,  `select ?x { }` and `select ?x WHERE {}` are the same).

Comment: And escapes are needed in the language tags, in `" FILTER ( lang(?n) = "fr" )"+`.  But on top of that, language tags should be compared with langMatches:  `filter langMatches(lang(?n),'fr')`.