# DBpedia query returns results with Virtuoso but not with Jena

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

I'm trying to create a SPARQL query with Jena to query DBpedia. The query is working when I use Virtuoso but when I plug it into the following Java code, it returns an empty set.

```java
String sr="Christopher_Nolan";
String sparqlQueryString1 = "PREFIX dbont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> "+            
        "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+ 
        "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> "+
        "   SELECT distinct   ?s"+        
        "   WHERE {  "+       
        "?s foaf:name ?label  ."  +
        "filter(?label=\"Christpher_Nolan\"@en)." +             
        "        }";
          Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQueryString1);
          QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);

          ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
          ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out,results, query);       

         qexec.close() ;
```

Comment: can someone help me to solve this problem please

Comment: Does a question like [Querying DBpedia with SPARQL and Jena](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1644252/1281433) help at all?

Comment: Should `"Christpher_Nolan"@en` be `"Christopher Nolan"@en`? (Note the `o`, and the space instead of underscore.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a problem with Jena, but with your particular query.  Your query, when run on the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint, produces no results

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT distinct ?s      
WHERE {
  ?s foaf:name ?label .
  filter(?label="Christpher_Nolan"@en)
}
```

[SPARQL results (no results)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs:%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf:%20%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20?s%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?s%20foaf:name%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28?label=%22Christpher_Nolan%22@en%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

[image: no results]

However, if you add an `o` to the name Christopher, and change the underscore to a space, you get three results:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT distinct ?s      
WHERE {
  ?s foaf:name ?label .
  filter(?label="Christopher Nolan"@en)
}
```

[SPARQL results (3 results)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs:%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf:%20%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20?s%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?s%20foaf:name%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28?label=%22Christopher%20Nolan%22@en%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

> **s**
>   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christopher_Nolan_(author)
>   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christopher_Nolan
>   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chris_Nolan_(musician)

[image: three results]

I'd also point out that this is a rather unusual use of `filter`.  If you want to select triples that use a certain value, just put that value into the triple pattern:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT distinct ?s      
WHERE {
  ?s foaf:name "Christopher Nolan"@en 
}
```

[SPARQL results (same 3 results)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs:%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf:%20%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20?s%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?s%20foaf:name%20%22Christopher%20Nolan%22@en%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: I tried to copy and paste your queries into the DBpedia. I got no result, it showed just the head of table.

Comment: @LVarayut DBpedia's endpoing can be a bit flaky at times, but I'm still able to copy and paste those queries to http://dbpedia.org/sparql and get the expected results. Note that the expected results are: no results for the first query, and three results for the second and third query. I've added screenshots as evidence. :)

Comment: Thanks for you respond. I was using [fr.dbpedia.org/sparql](http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql) and it doesn't work. I just tried with [dbpedia.org/sparql](http://dbpedia.org/sparql). It worked like a charm. Could you explain a little bit `what is Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI)` and what should I put in there?

Comment: @LVarayut Yes, as I recall, the localized DBpedias don't have all the multi-lingual data, so the French DBpedia very well might not have the English data.